# Put self.editbuttonitem into segmentedcontrol as barbuttonitem?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to make a NavBar similar to the one in sample 3 of the [NavBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/NavBar/Listings/PageThreeViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-PageThreeViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_19) sample code, except I want to use the self.editbuttonItem as one of the two buttons in the SegmentedControl. (The other will be a custom add button.) Basically - the end result will be a leftBarButtonItem that's just one button, bringing up a modal view, and a rightBarButtonItem that's a segmented control with both edit and add buttons.

Thing is, it looks like setting up the SegmentedControl needs an array of Strings or Images, but not BarButtonItems. Is there a workaround?

This is the relevant bit from Apple's sample:

```
    // "Segmented" control to the right
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"],
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"],
                                             nil]];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, kCustomButtonHeight);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

defaultTintColor = [segmentedControl.tintColor retain]; // keep track of this for later

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
[segmentBarItem release];
```

Instead of the images, I want to put BarButtonItems...

Comment: Alternatively, if I could just put three buttons up in the toolbar that'd be even better... One on the left, two on the right - but I get errors when I try to use self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `self.editbuttonitem` is a UIBarButtonItem with title "Edit", I think you can do with the following code

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                            @"Edit", @"AnotherButtonName"
                                         nil]];
```

**edit based on Charles Bandes's comment**

Add an action to the `segmentedControl`, like the Apple's sample:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//...
```

then in `segmentAction:`, do

```
- (void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    //if the "edit" item in segmentedControl is selected
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        //I assume self is a UITableView instance
        //start editing
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I wrote those code on my PC. However it should work.

You may take a look at [[UITableView setEditing:animated:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/setEditing%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: self.editbuttonitem is something that is generated automatically by the uitableview

Comment: If so, the `segmentedControl` can do that `editbuttonitem`'s job, plz check my edit.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Only remaining challenge is getting it to change the label from "edit" to "done" depending on editing state

Comment: you can use `[segmentedControl setTitle:@"Done" forSegmentAtIndex:0]` for that, you may check Apple's doc for more details on how to use them.